# Expanding a compound differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Would it be a valid statement to say that we can write the following differential $$d(uv)$$ as $$d(uv)=v(du)+u(dv)$$

Comment: It may depend on whether you allow a naked $dx$. Is your expression equivalent to  $\dfrac{d(uv)}{dx}=v\dfrac{du}{dx}+u\dfrac{dv}{dx}$?

Comment: Yes, that ought to hold, but _why_ it holds depends on which formalism you're working in. Sometimes it's an _axiom_. Exactly what kind of thing is a differential for you here?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate an equation of the form: $$dy = k_{1} du + k_{2} d(uv)+k_{3}dv$$ where k1, k2 and k3 are constants.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int d\alpha=\alpha$